# Concatenate matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am trying to combine the two column-vectors `distance` and `time` into one $ 6 \times 2 $ matrix, `data`. I am first combining data in seconds and minutes into data in minutes first, which I think is the root of the problem. If I do this operation, `data` comes out as a $ 12\times 1 $ matrix. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
distance = Transpose[{{0, 0.76, 1.77, 2.52, 3.6, 3.84}}]
sec = {{0, 11.25, 42.84, 2.9, 58.11, 55.28}};
min = {{0, 6, 14, 21, 29, 31}};
time = min + sec/60;
time = Transpose[time];
data = {distance, time};
```

Comment: One problem is that you're using $1\times n$ matrices and not vectors. Try e.g. `MapThread[{Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{#1, #2}], MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}]], Quantity[#3, "Inches"]} &, {{0, 6, 14, 21, 29, 31}, {0, 11.25, 42.84, 2.9, 58.11, 55.28}, {0, 0.76, 1.77, 2.52, 3.6, 3.84}}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
time = min + sec/60;
data = Join[distance, List /@ Flatten@time, 2]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0.76, 6.1875}, {1.77, 14.714}, {2.52, 21.0483}, {3.6, 29.9685}, {3.84, 31.9213}}
> ```

Comment: I get "Join::normal1: Expression {0,0.76,1.77,2.52,3.6,3.84} at position 1 is expected to have nonatomic subexpression at level 2." for this.  A goofy workaround is  data = Join[List /@ distance, List /@ Flatten@time, 2]

Answer (score 2):

This may be performed in a much simpler manner:

```
distance1 = {0, 0.76, 1.77, 2.52, 3.6, 3.84};
sec1 = {0, 11.25, 42.84, 2.9, 58.11, 55.28};
min1 = {0, 6, 14, 21, 29, 31};
time1 = min1 + sec1/60;
data1 = Transpose@{distance1, time1};
data1


(* {{0, 0}, {0.76, 6.1875}, {1.77, 14.714}, {2.52, 21.0483}, {3.6, 
  29.9685}, {3.84, 31.9213}} *)
```

So, effectively, in this case, you may merely make the `List`s of your values, then, provided they are the same length, `Transpose` a `List` of those `List`s made previously to combine them together.

Kindly, let me know if you need any additional clarifications on this!

Answer (score 2):

Why not a simple `Thread`? Simplifying the initial sets,

```
distance = {0, 0.76, 1.77, 2.52, 3.6, 3.84};
sec = {0, 11.25, 42.84, 2.9, 58.11, 55.28};
min = {0, 6, 14, 21, 29, 31};
time = min + sec/60;

Thread[{distance, time}]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0.76, 6.1875}, {1.77, 14.714}, {2.52, 21.0483}, {3.6, 
>     29.9685}, {3.84, 31.9213}}